# How to retrive as custom object using Firebase RTDB

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class FireStoreData  {

private String brgy;
private String street;
private String date;
private String  time;
private GeoPoint location;
private String item;


public FireStoreData(){

}

public FireStoreData(String brgy, String street, String date, String time, GeoPoint location, String item) {
    .....
}
```

...

Here is my database
[my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvTRr.png)

This is my code for retrieving data

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child( "CrimeReport" ).get().addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
            }
            else {


                Toast.makeText( requireContext(), "Data"+ task.getResult().getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
            }
        }
    } );
```

This is the received data.

```
 {Palatie={Robbery={Report={date=02/28/22, item=Robbery, street=Santos, location={latitude=14.561677776545071, longitude=121.08633846044542}, time=12:0 AM, brgy=Palatie}}, Hijacking={Report={date=02/23/22, item=Hijacking, street=Santos, location={latitude=14.561677776545071, longitude=121.08633846044542}, time=12:0 AM, brgy=Palatie}}}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change the database schema?

Comment: yes we are allowed to do our own database schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual database doesn't allow you to simply query the data. Since you're already storing the date into the `date` filed, you can remove one level in your three like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- CrimeReport
        |
        --- Baltazar
              |
              --- Robbery
                    |
                    --- $pushedId
                           |
                           --- brgy: "Baltazar"
                           |
                           --- date: "Feb 14, 2022"
                           |
                           --- \\The other fields.
```

Now to be able to read the data, you need to create a reference that points exactly to the `Robbery` node and then attach a listener as below:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference robberyRef = db.child("CrimeReport").child("Baltazar").child("Robbery");
robberyRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String brgy = ds.child("brgy").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", brgy);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Baltazar
```

In the same way, I read the value of the `brgy` field, you can also read the remaining ones.

If you want to map the result into an object of type `FireStoreData`, then instead of reading each value, you can map it directly using:

```
FireStoreData data = ds.getValue(FireStoreData.class);
Log.d("TAG", data.getBrgy());
```

This will produce the same result as above.

Comment: I have an error when I map the result  "no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to FireStoreData"

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, my bad. I just updated my answer. It should be `FireStoreData data = ds.getValue(FireStoreData.class);` Does it work now?